# Full screen, lower resolution guest on parallels

Tags: mac, parallels

I have a Macbook Pro with Parallels. I want to run a guest Windows VM at lower than native res, say 1024x768 not 1440x900 (or whatever the Mac is).

I can't see how to do this though? The VM just runs 'native' but with a thick black border. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm haven't used Parallels, but I assume it has this feature (VMware does): start a VNC server for your Windows virtual machine. Then connect to it from your Mac and run the VNC session fullscreen. The Screen Sharing VNC client built into Snow Leopard and later does not appear to have a fullscreen option, nor the ability to increase the size of the window beyond the size of the virtual screen, however some third-party VNC clients do; I just tried it with [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) and it worked fine.